# JavasScript not working in android's 4.4.3 webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

One of android apps was using Mathjax JavaScript library to render mathematical symbols , using android webview.

My app had an html file and was using the MathJax JavaScript file, but after the 4.4.3 update from google, the javascript from the html file is not getting loaded. Entire html is getting loaded without issues, but JS is refusing to load no problem whatever i do.

I have enabled javascript already using:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Any clues why this is happening and how to over come this ??

Comment: try `webView.setWebChromeClient(new InredisChromeClient(this));
webView.setWebViewClient(new InredisWebViewClient(this));
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`

Comment: what is InredisChromeClient and InredisWebViewClient ??

Comment: Sorry,,try this `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(this));
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient(this));
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`

Comment: i dont think WebChromClient constructor can take activity object in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect chrome dev tools to debug the WebView? There may be an error in the console.

Comment: Hi Thanks you mean to say there can be error in JavaScript files and that's why its not getting evaluated ??

Comment: Quite possible - debugging instructions are here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Ok i will do that now, but i am kind of curious why that was working fine with 4.4.2 and started not working with 4.4.3 !!

Comment: The WebView implementation was upgraded in 4.4.3, it could be a change in the V8 engine. Can you share the JavaScript code?